# Как вытащить иконку приложения из файла apk на node.js

Tags: android, node.js, apk

Задний конец на node.js.

Заливаем файлы .apk на сервер, а мобильный клиент потом получает список доступных приложений.

Руками заливать картинки отдельно неудобно.

Есть ли способ вытащить иконку из файла средствами node.js?

Уточнение:
пробовал разбирать .apk руками и искать иконку, чтобы понять систему по которой определяется путь по которому лежит иконка.
Систему эту понять не смог. Только то, что иконка чаще всего лежит в папке, которая в названии содержит подстроку drawable-hdpi, которая лежит в папке res. Но не обязательно. Бывает вообще нет файла с названием похожим на icon.

Распарсил манифест и нашел в нем такую запись:

```
application: {
     theme: 'resourceId:0x7f110007',
     label: 'resourceId:0x7f100020',
     icon: 'resourceId:0x7f0e0000',
     много еще чего...
}
```

Что такое 0x7f0e0000? Можно ли из этой записи определить путь до иконки?

Comment: .apk файл это zip архив, попробуйте исходить из этого. Распаковывать zip архивы node умеет из коробки. Вам останется только из настроек прочитать путь к иконке.

Comment: Вам нужно программно вызвать `aapt`

Comment: @Nick ясно, спасибо! А можете тогда подсказать, какую команду в этой утилите нужно ввести чтобы получить иконку? я совсем не андроид разработчик